# Admob not working in android build. Works perfectly in unity editor

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I created a project in unity to try Admob in an android game. The ad works whitout a problem while in the editor but when I build the game and play it on android, it doesn't load the ad.

The project has only one script:

```
﻿using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using GoogleMobileAds.Common;
using System;

public class RewardedAd : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5354046379";

    public Text errorText;
    public Text message1;
    public Text message2;
    public Text message3;
    public Text message4;
    public Text message5;
    public Text rewardText;

    private RewardedInterstitialAd rewardedInterstitialAd;

    void Start()
    {
        RequestRewardedInterstitial();
    }

    void RequestRewardedInterstitial()
    {
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // Load the rewarded ad with the request.
        RewardedInterstitialAd.LoadAd(adUnitId, request, adLoadCallback);
    }

    private void adLoadCallback(RewardedInterstitialAd ad, string error)
    {
        if (error == null)
        {
            rewardedInterstitialAd = ad;

            rewardedInterstitialAd.OnAdFailedToPresentFullScreenContent += HandleAdFailedToPresent;
            rewardedInterstitialAd.OnAdDidPresentFullScreenContent += HandleAdDidPresent;
            rewardedInterstitialAd.OnAdDidDismissFullScreenContent += HandleAdDidDismiss;
            rewardedInterstitialAd.OnPaidEvent += HandlePaidEvent;
        }
        else
        {
            errorText.text = error;
        }
    }

    public void ShowRewardedInterstitialAd()
    {
        if (rewardedInterstitialAd != null)
        {
            rewardedInterstitialAd.Show(userEarnedRewardCallback);
            RequestRewardedInterstitial();
        }
        else
        {
            message1.text = "rewardedInterstitialAd is null";
        }
    }

    private void userEarnedRewardCallback(Reward reward)
    {
        //Reward the user.
        rewardText.text = "Win reward";
    }

    private void HandleAdFailedToPresent(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        message2.text = "Rewarded interstitial ad has failed to present.";
    }

    private void HandleAdDidPresent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        message3.text = "Rewarded interstitial ad has presented.";
    }

    private void HandleAdDidDismiss(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        message4.text = "Rewarded interstitial ad has dismissed presentation.";
    }

    private void HandlePaidEvent(object sender, AdValueEventArgs args)
    {
        message5.text = "Rewarded interstitial ad has received a paid event.";
    }
}
```

In the editor you only need to create a canvas with a button and 7 text fields. Add the script to any gameobject and set the text fields to the script "Text" variables, then set the OnClick() event of the button to ShowRewardedInterstitialAd().

Also I have already set the "GoogleMobileAdsSettings"->Android to my app id(ca-app-pub-xxxxx~xxxxx).

As I already mentioned it works just fine in unity, displaying the ad and the messages:

- "Rewarded interstitial ad has presented."
- "Rewarded interstitial ad has dismissed presentation."
- "Win reward"

In contrast on android when I click the button it only displays the message:

- "rewardedInterstitialAd is null"

I'm currently using the Admob test ads. How can I get this working on android?

Answer (score 1):

Resolve your Libraries with external dependency manager and enable jetifier in external dependency manager.
here is the link to down load external dependency manager
https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

Or

Always try to test ads by testing ID's below some testing ID's by Admob

```
Ad format   Sample ad unit ID
App Open    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294
Banner  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
Interstitial    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
Interstitial Video  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433
Rewarded    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917
Rewarded Interstitial   ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5354046379
Native Advanced ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110
Native Advanced Video   ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1044960115
```

and one more thing, you can add your device as a testing device. Follow below Steps

```
Add your test device programmatically
    If you want to test ads in your app as you're developing, follow the steps below to programmatically register your test device.
    
Load your ads-integrated app and make an ad request.
Check the logcat output for a message that looks like the one below, which shows you your device ID and how to add it as a test device:

I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder.setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231"))
to get test ads on this device."
Copy your test device ID to your clipboard.
Modify your code to call RequestConfiguration.Builder.setTestDeviceIds().
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem with Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v8.2.0.
The ads work well in Unity Editor and Development build, but just do not work with production build.

I run the test APK with android studio, it will return errors with some classes not found, so I unchecked the "Minify -> Release", and it works fine.

It sounds like proguard problems.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34387916)